# Show IDs for the highest MAX values in a matrix

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have a matrix that's grouped by different company brands. Essentially, I'm showing the highest value spent by a customer for each company brand (I've used MAX in my expression to get those). I also want to show Customer IDs attributed to those MAX values. Does anybody know how to do that? Is there any expression?

Example:

Company Brand: Nike | Max value spent: £500 | Customer ID: ???

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to get these values from your query?  `SELECT CustomerID FROM Customers WHERE CompanyID = @CompanyID AND MAX(ValueSpent) = ValueSpent` Something along those lines?

Comment: Could you please show us what Field (attributes) are you retrieving in your dataset. Does your query not have customerId field??

Answer (score 0):

You can use subqueries to retrieve summed values in your SQL Query

```
SELECT T1.CustomerID, T1.CompanyBrand,
    (SELECT Max(S1.ValueSpentField) FROM TableThatContainsValueSpent S1 WHERE T1.CustomerID = S1.CustomerID)
FROM Company T1
```